# Nodejs - Hosting to subroute

Tags: node.js, api, routes, hosting

I want to host my nodejs server application in a sub route in iis. What i want to do is host my application as such localhost:3000/node/ not localhost:3000/.
This can be achieved by

changing endpoints from

```
app.get('/', moduleRoutes.root);
app.post('/auth/signup/', authenticationRoutes.signup);
```

to

```
app.get('/node/', moduleRoutes.root);
app.post('/node/auth/signup/', authenticationRoutes.signup);
```

but i don't want to change all the api endpoint every time I change my hosting path.

another is

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    //change request location from here by changing 
    req.url = req.url.replace('localhost:3000/node/', 'localhost:3000') 
    //somthing like that
    authorization.memberinfo(req, res, next);
});
```

but this does not look like a proper way to achieve this. Please direct me toward the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just mount a router at `/node` and just add all of your routes to that router instead:

```
// These three lines could even be placed in a separate file that you
// would `require()` and use in your app.js
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', moduleRoutes.root);
router.post('/auth/signup/', authenticationRoutes.signup);

app.use('/node', router);
```